# How to set drag X limit

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm working on some draggable/droppable bar.So it's draggable only x because this is select bar.Problem is select button draggable out of stage limit. I want to draggable only in stage limit.I tried some methods hitTestPoint and newshape but it didn't work.

```
// define lock on y-axis
var LOCKY:Number = secbuton.y;
 
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, _mouseMove);
function _mouseMove(e:MouseEvent):void
{
if(secbuton.y != LOCKY) secbuton.y = LOCKY;
}
 
// dragging
secbuton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, _mouseDown);
function _mouseDown(e:MouseEvent):void
{
secbuton.startDrag(false, new Rectangle(35,345,420));
secbuton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, _mouseUp);
}
 
// dropping
function _mouseUp(e:MouseEvent):void
{
secbuton.stopDrag();
secbuton.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, _mouseUp);

            if(secbuton.hitTestObject(kose1)){
    secbuton.x = levcbk1.x +5  
    }

    if(secbuton.hitTestObject(lev2)){
    secbuton.x = levcbk2.x +5  
    }
 if(secbuton.hitTestObject(lev3)){
    secbuton.x = levcbk3.x +5
    }
                 if(secbuton.hitTestObject(lev4)){
    secbuton.x = levcbk4.x +5
    }

                         if(secbuton.hitTestObject(lev5)){
    secbuton.x = levcbk5.x +5
    }
}
```

UPDATE

Normally bar work like this.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

But problem is there when hit the borders or when try drag to y axis.

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Comment: Second argument: **public function startDrag(lockCenter:Boolean = false, bounds:Rectangle = null):void** http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Sprite.html#startDrag()

Comment: I'm new on class.I'm using frame code.How can I do that in frame code ?

Comment: **secbuton.startDrag(false, new Rectangle(...));** and in the Rectangle constructor you pass **left, top, width, height** of the rectangular area that should be a bounding box for dragging your secbutton object.

Comment: @Organis now stage limit working,but it always dragging when hit the limits or when try drag to y axis.My rules work like ...MOUSE_DOWN = drag MOUSE_UP drop.But it keep moving anyway.So secbuton follow to mousex without mouse click.

Comment: What do you mean the limits work but it keeps dragging? Isn't the point of the limits to make it not drag past a certain point? Or do you mean that mouse_up event isn't working and you aren't able to drop it?  Sorry. Just a little unclear on what the current problem is.

Comment: @KucuKeko Because MOUSE_UP happens only when mouse button is released within the subscribed object. I explained it not long ago: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42542667/4687633

Comment: MOUSE_LEAVE didn't work.Updated first message.You can see the issue to second gif.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `MOUSE_LEAVE`. Use `MOUSE_UP` but on `stage` object - `MOUSE_UP` is dispatched by `stage` object even it you release button outside the flash player window (basically anywhere)

So simply change those lines

```
secbuton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, _mouseUp);
secbuton.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, _mouseUp);
```

to this:

```
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, _mouseUp);
stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, _mouseUp);
```

And as Organis said. `Rectangle` parameters are `x , y , width and height`.
So from what I see on the gifs you want set it to:

`secbuton.startDrag(false, new Rectangle(35,345,420-35,0));`

If you set rectangle heigh to `0`, your object will be locked on y-axis (345 in your case) so you don't need to use the `LOCKY` variable and move listener.