# Playing sounds on Actionscript

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a simple drag and drop game started in flash and mostly working.

I have added my animals and you can drag and drop them in the right place.I have also added sound so that when the animal is dropped in the right spot , that is working however each time I add a new animal to the right spot it plays that sound and the last animal sound as well.

**e.g**. place pig in pig space , it plays pig sound
place cow in cow space , it plays cow sound and pig sound
place duck in duck space , it plays duck sound and cow sound and pig sound.

Obviously I only want to play the sound when the animal is placed in the right place - on drop ( not on next animal drop also )

I'm not sure what I have done wrong

/* Drag and Drop
Makes the specified symbol instance moveable with drag and drop.
*/

```
 import flash.media.Sound;
  var offset:int = 10;

  var pigStartX:int = 196.80;
  var pigStartY:int = 292.10;

  var pigEndX:int = 578.40;
  var pigEndY:int = 208.50;

  Pig.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, fl_ClickToDrag);

  function fl_ClickToDrag(event:MouseEvent):void
  {
  Pig.startDrag();
   }

 stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, fl_ReleaseToDrop);

  function fl_ReleaseToDrop(event:MouseEvent):void
   {
  Pig.stopDrag();
// dragging and dropping the pieces while checking for correct   location 

    if(Pig.x < pigEndX - offset || Pig.x > pigEndX + offset || Pig.y <    pigEndY - offset ||Pig.y > pigEndY + offset){

    Pig.x = pigStartX;
    Pig.y = pigStartY;
}

  else{

     //set piece back to original position
     Pig.x = pigEndX;
     Pig.y = pigEndY;

     var oink:PigOink = new PigOink(); 
     var channel:SoundChannel = oink.play();
    //checkGame();

}
}
```

/* Drag and Drop
Makes the specified symbol instance moveable with drag and drop.
*/

```
 var cowStartX:int = 324;
 var cowStartY:int = 317.95;

 var cowEndX:int = 411.50;
 var cowEndY:int = 140.95;

   Cow.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, fl_ClickToDrag_2);

  function fl_ClickToDrag_2(event:MouseEvent):void
  {
    Cow.startDrag();
  }

  stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, fl_ReleaseToDrop_2);

 function fl_ReleaseToDrop_2(event:MouseEvent):void
 {
    Cow.stopDrag();
// dragging and dropping the pieces while checking for correct  location 
 if(Cow.x < cowEndX - offset || Cow.x > cowEndX + offset || Cow.y <  cowEndY - offset ||Cow.y > cowEndY + offset){

      Cow.x = cowStartX;
      Cow.y = cowStartY;
 }

  else{

    //set piece back to original position
      Cow.x = cowEndX;
      Cow.y = cowEndY;

    var moo:CowMoo = new CowMoo(); 
    var channel:SoundChannel = moo.play();
    //checkGame();

}

}
```

/* Drag and Drop
Makes the specified symbol instance moveable with drag and drop.
*/

```
   var duckStartX:int = 209.45;
   var duckStartY:int = 402.05;

   var duckEndX:int = 56.45;
   var duckEndY:int = 225.05;

  Duck.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, fl_ClickToDrag_3);

  function fl_ClickToDrag_3(event:MouseEvent):void
  {
     Duck.startDrag();
   }

  stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, fl_ReleaseToDrop_3);

  function fl_ReleaseToDrop_3(event:MouseEvent):void
  {
     Duck.stopDrag();
// dragging and dropping the pieces while checking for correct location 
     if(Duck.x < duckEndX - offset || Duck.x > duckEndX + offset ||   Duck.y < duckEndY - offset ||Duck.y > duckEndY + offset){

    //set piece back to original position
        Duck.x = duckStartX;
        Duck.y = duckStartY;
     }

     else{


        Duck.x = duckEndX;
        Duck.y = duckEndY;

        var quack:DuckQuack = new DuckQuack(); 
        var channel:SoundChannel = quack.play();
    //checkGame();
   }


   }
```

Comment: First of all, rid of extra code you have there. Instead 3 pieces of similar code you need some kind of DraggableAnimal class that have some data: origin:Point, destination:Point, voice:Class, image:Sprite, etc. Then you create 3 instances of this class and fill them with appropriate data. The problem just might resolve itself by that time.

Comment: Thanks but I am pretty new to this and trying to get it fixed the way I understand first .I know your way would be much more efficient and tidy but want to get this fixed first - any ideas?

Comment: Sure. You subscribe 3 methods for the same MOUSE_UP event and all 3 fires at once. You can just click stage without dragging and still get all the sounds, I think. To avoid it, you need to subscribe for MOUSE_UP **only** when you start dragging an animal.

Comment: Hi Organis, Thanks for the reply , I changed the Mouse event handlers as and it is now working, thanks for all your feedback and help :-)

Comment: @ladybug Welcome to StackOverflow. You must accept answers by clicking the `✔` icon next to the best Answer. This helps others know there is a working solution & closes the current issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at your MouseUp event handlers.

You are adding the event listener to the stage. So they are all getting called whenever the stage hears a mouse up event.

Add those listeners to the cow, pig etc just as you did for the mouse down listeners.

That should solve it.

```
Pig.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, fl_ClickToDrag);

  function fl_ClickToDrag(event:MouseEvent):void
  {
  Pig.startDrag();
   }

 //stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, fl_ReleaseToDrop);
  // change to this
 Pig.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, fl_ReleaseToDrop);
```

Comment: But this will probably lead again to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42585933/how-to-set-drag-x-limit/42604109#42604109 problem.

Comment: @ladybug so press that "**√**" icon to accepting true answer

Comment: @PawełAudionysos I don't think OP is trying to limit where the animals can be dragged like that secbuton.

Comment: buy if you move your mouse outside the flash player window  and release the button there it's going to stuck on been dragged. It was shown on gifs I don't know what happened to them...

Comment: @PawełAudionysos Indeed but we could add a mouseLeave listener. Yes, we are putting band-aids on a nicked artery, but the OP says they don't want to make a DraggableAnimal class as Organis suggested so I don't see another way.

Comment: @PawełAudionysos and btw, the mouse leaving the window and then being released wouldn't trigger a mouseUp event anyway. If you are using a stage based mouseUp listener you still need to handle the mouseLeave event separately.

Comment: But he don't need to use Animal class. He can just remove his listener in code he already have - I edited my answer so it's more clear. "the mouse leaving the window and then being released wouldn't trigger a mouseUp event anyway." No, it WILL trigger as I said i the linked answer. Try it.

Comment: @PawełAudionysos oh I didn't know that. Ok I agree, just removing the eventlistener is a cleaner solution in that case. +1

Comment: Well, it's logical to assume that it wont trigger the event. I also probably found this out by accident... :)

Answer (score 2):

@Neal Davis is right about what is causing the problem, however I suggest to remove event listener once the animal is its destination position instead of listening `MOUSE_UP` event on the animal itself in release function:

```
function fl_ReleaseToDrop_3(event:MouseEvent):void {
    stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, fl_ReleaseToDrop_3);
    Pig.stopDrag();
    //...
}
```

#### Aditional suggestion.

Also as @Organis pointed out. It's much simpler to have more generic code.
Consider having something like this:

**Document class:**

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.geom.Point;

    public class Main extends Sprite
    {
        private var animals:Vector.<Animal> = Vector.<Animal>([]);

        public function Main() {
            animals.push(new Animal("pig", pigMc, 578, 208, "oink.mp3"));
            animals.push(new Animal("cow", cowMc, 411, 140, "moo.mp3"));
            animals.push(new Animal("duck", duckMc, 56, 225, "quack.mp3"));
        }

    }

}
```

**And simple Animal class:**

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.geom.Point;
    import flash.media.Sound;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;

    public class Animal
    {
        private var _name:String;
        private var _dropMargin:Number = 10;
        private var _startPos:Point = new Point();
        private var _endPos:Point = new Point();
        private var _sound:Sound;
        private var _view:Sprite;

        public function Animal(name:String, view:Sprite, endX:Number = 0, endY:Number = 0, sound:String = null) {
            _name = name;
            _view = view;
            _startPos.x = _view.x; _startPos.y = _view.y;
            _endPos.x = endX; _endPos.y = endY;
            _sound = new Sound(new URLRequest(sound));
            view.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onMDown);
        }

        private function onMDown(e:MouseEvent):void{
            _view.stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onMUp);
            _view.startDrag();
        }

        private function onMUp(e:MouseEvent):void {
            _view.stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onMUp);
            _view.stopDrag();
            //Distance to destination point
            var dd:Number = Point.distance(pos, _endPos);

            if (dd > dropMargin) pos = _startPos;
            else {
                pos = _endPos;
                _sound.play();
            }
        }

        public function get view():Sprite{return _view;}

        public function get dropMargin():Number{return _dropMargin;}
        public function set dropMargin(value:Number):void{_dropMargin = value;}

        public function get pos():Point{return new Point(_view.x, _view.y);}
        public function set pos(value:Point):void{
            _view.x = value.x;
            _view.y = value.y;
        }

    }

}
```