# Syntax error - rightparen - ActionScript 3 - using an array

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, flash

I'm creating a custom Adobe Connect pod, a simple drag and drop in AS3 - which currently works in Adobe Connect, and has no bugs. It doesn't work with the SyncConnector elements though, which is where I'm struggling.

I've found a post elsewhere that suggests using each of my drag/drop items as an array. I've set up an array at the top of the code, then I have my drag/drop code, then my final parts for the Sync at the end. I'm getting a syntax error of "expecting rightparen before dot", which is for me - confusing - as I'm very new to AS3.

I'd really appreciate someone showing me the correct code I'd need, as I don't fully understand the terminology. I do literally need it spelt out for me. Full code below, happy to pay for someones time if this isn't an easy fix:

```
import com.adobe.sync.components.SyncConnector;
import com.adobe.sync.events.SyncSwfEvent;

var connector:SyncConnector;

function init(c:SyncConnector):void 

{

connector=c;

}


// Keep stage reference here.
var draggedStage:Stage;

// Keep dragged item reference here.
var draggedItem:InteractiveObject;

// The list of items to drag.
var aList:Array =
[
    AirBP,PetroChem,LiquifiedGas,Exploration,Plastic,
    BiofuelsFarm,Trading,Electricity,Development,
    Production,Distribution,Lubes,Retail,Shipping,
    Refining,BPMarine,Terminal,Terminal2,Pipeline,
    Pipeline2,SugarCane,WindPower
];

// Subscribe all items for MOUSE_DOWN event.
for each (draggedItem in aList)
    draggedItem.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onDrag);

function onDrag(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    // Get the source of event.
    draggedItem = e.target as InteractiveObject;
    draggedItem.startDrag();

    // Hook the stage events for MOUSE_UP event. You can skip using "draggedStage"
    // if you are sure that stage reference  is always available.
    draggedStage = dtaggedItem.stage;
    draggedStage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onDrop);
}

function onDrop(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    // Stopp dragging things.
    draggedItem.stopDrag();

    // Unhook stage for it is no longer needed.
    draggedStage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onDrop);

    // Forget the references.
    draggedItem = null;
    draggedStage = null;
}

connector.dispatchSyncMessage("dragdrop", myObj, true);

connector.addEventListener(SyncSwfEvent.SYNC_MSG_RCVD, mouseListen);

function mouseListen(e.SyncSwfEvent):void 

{
    if (e.data.msgNm == "dragdrop") {
         myObj = e.data.msgVal as Array;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The advice was exactly right. Make your code simpler because it is easy to miss a syntax error in that huge chunk of they-all-look-alike-oh-my-eyes lines of code. All your unreadable listeners should be replaced with this:

```
// Keep stage reference here.
var draggedStage:Stage;

// Keep dragged item reference here.
var draggedItem:InteractiveObject;

// The list of items to drag.
var aList:Array =
[
    AirBP,PetroChem,LiquifiedGas,Exploration,Plastic,
    BiofuelsFarm,Trading,Electricity,Development,
    Production,Distribution,Lubes,Retail,Shipping,
    Refining,BPMarine,Terminal,Terminal2,Pipeline,
    Pipeline2,SugarCane,WindPower
];

// Subscribe all items for MOUSE_DOWN event.
for each (draggedItem in aList)
    draggedItem.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onDrag);

function onDrag(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    // Get the source of event.
    draggedItem = e.target as InteractiveObject;
    draggedItem.startDrag();
    
    // Hook the stage events for MOUSE_UP event. You can skip using "draggedStage"
    // if you are sure that stage reference  is always available.
    draggedStage = draggedItem.stage;
    draggedStage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onDrop);
}

function onDrop(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    // Stopp dragging things.
    draggedItem.stopDrag();
    
    // Unhook stage for it is no longer needed.
    draggedStage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onDrop);
    
    // Forget the references.
    draggedItem = null;
    draggedStage = null;
}
```

Another one of my drag-n-drop related answers is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42542667/4687633

Comment: Thank you for taking the time, I really appreciate it. I've just added your code in, and I'm still getting the "expecting rightparen before dot" error. Any help?

Comment: You should **replace** your code with mine, not add it.

Comment: Hi, I replaced with your code, still the same error. I need to keep the very top of my code to import the adobe flash events to allow it to play in Adobe Connect. I also need to keep the very bottom to search for the array. I'll update the code in the main message to show what it looks like now, but this is still bringing up the original error message. Any ideas?

Comment: @Newtothis Is it a frame script or a class?

Comment: I don't know how to find that out. I'm literally a few days into AS3, so I'm very new and very inexperienced. As I say, happy to pay for an hour of someones time to fix my code and help me get the Sync Connector functions working.

Comment: @Newtothis Read this: http://www.untoldentertainment.com/blog/2009/08/25/tutorial-understanding-classes-in-as3-part-1/

Comment: it's all in one layer. Looks like the "intermediate" section of the article you posted?

Comment: @Newtothis So, it's a frame script. Now, go to File > Publish Settings > SWF > Permit Debugging > check it. This will give you the exact frame, layer and line that produce the mentioned error, and you will be able to pinpoint the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This error usually means there is a syntax error. Please change

```
function mouseListen(e.SyncSwfEvent):void
```

to

```
function mouseListen(e:SyncSwfEvent):void
```