# How to make drag and drop in action script3.0 doesnt overlapping

Tags: actionscript-3, drag-and-drop

So I am making it like a drag and drop quiz, there is two answer box where you can drop your answer in it, so my problem is that when I drop an answer on one answer box, I want the other answer to not be able to drop into the same answer box.
if can, I want when I drop the answer, when I try to drop the other answer into it, it will make the answer back to its place
[pics of the quiz](https://i.stack.imgur.com/220Vw.jpg)

```
stop();
/* Drag and Drop
Makes the specified symbol instance moveable with drag and drop.
*/
var skor4:int = 0;
skor3.text = String(skor4);

function jumlah2(){
   skor4=skor4+1;
}
tick1.visible=false;
tick2.visible=false;

cross1.visible=false;
cross.visible=false;

meso1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, fl_ClickToDrag);

function fl_ClickToDrag(event:MouseEvent):void
{
   meso1.startDrag();
   
}

meso1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, fl_ReleaseToDrop);

function fl_ReleaseToDrop(event:MouseEvent):void
{
   meso1.stopDrag();   
   if(meso1.hitTestObject(ruang))
   {
           jumlah2();
   skor3.text=String(skor4);
       
       meso1.x=269.4;
       meso1.y=359.45;
       tick1.visible=true;

   meso1.mouseEnabled=false;

   }
else if(meso1.hitTestObject(ruangg))
   {
       
       meso1.x=581.95;
       meso1.y=359.45;
       cross1.visible=true;
       
           Mesir1.mouseEnabled=false;
   
   Indus1.mouseEnabled=false;
       
   }
else{
   meso1.x=648;
   meso1.y=455.5;
}

}


/* Drag and Drop
Makes the specified symbol instance moveable with drag and drop.
*/

Indus1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, fl_ClickToDrag_2);

function fl_ClickToDrag_2(event:MouseEvent):void
{
   Indus1.startDrag();
   
}

Indus1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, fl_ReleaseToDrop_2);

function fl_ReleaseToDrop_2(event:MouseEvent):void
{
   Indus1.stopDrag();
   
   if(Indus1.hitTestObject(ruang))
   {
       Indus1.x=269.4;
       Indus1.y=359.45;
       cross.visible=true;
   Indus1.mouseEnabled=false;  
       
   }
else if(Indus1.hitTestObject(ruangg))
   {
       Indus1.x=581.95;
       Indus1.y=359.45;
       cross1.visible=true;
       Indus1.mouseEnabled=false;
       Mesir1.mouseEnabled=false;

   meso1.mouseEnabled=false;
       
   }
else{
   Indus1.x=433.95;
   Indus1.y=455.5;
}

}


/* Drag and Drop
Makes the specified symbol instance moveable with drag and drop.
*/





/* Drag and Drop
Makes the specified symbol instance moveable with drag and drop.
*/

Mesir1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, fl_ClickToDrag_4);

function fl_ClickToDrag_4(event:MouseEvent):void
{
   Mesir1.startDrag();

}

Mesir1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, fl_ReleaseToDrop_4);

function fl_ReleaseToDrop_4(event:MouseEvent):void
{
   Mesir1.stopDrag();
   if(Mesir1.hitTestObject(ruang))
   {
       Mesir1.x=269.4;
       Mesir1.y=359.45;
       cross.visible=true;
   Mesir1.mouseEnabled=false;
   }
else if(Mesir1.hitTestObject(ruangg))
   {
       jumlah2();
   skor3.text=String(skor4);
       Mesir1.x=581.95;
       Mesir1.y=359.45;
       tick2.visible=true;
       
       meso1.mouseEnabled=false;

   Indus1.mouseEnabled=false;
   }
else{
   Mesir1.x=226.85;
   Mesir1.y=455.5;
}

}

/* Click to Go to Frame and Play
Clicking on the specified symbol instance moves the playhead to the specified frame in the timeline and continues playback from that frame.
Can be used on the main timeline or on movie clip timelines.

Instructions:
1. Replace the number 5 in the code below with the frame number you would like the playhead to move to when the symbol instance is clicked.
*/

cont.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoToAndPlayFromFrame_31);

function fl_ClickToGoToAndPlayFromFrame_31(event:MouseEvent):void
{
   gotoAndPlay(2);
}

/* Drag and Drop
Makes the specified symbol instance moveable with drag and drop.
*/



/* Click to Go to Scene and Play
Clicking on the specified symbol instance plays the movie from the specified scene and frame.

Instructions:
1. Replace "Scene 3" with the name of the scene you would like play.
2. Replace 1 with the frame number you would like the movie to play from in the specified scene.
*/

home3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoToScene_76);

function fl_ClickToGoToScene_76(event:MouseEvent):void
{
   MovieClip(this.root).gotoAndPlay(1, "Scene 2");
}
```

Comment: Use algorithmic approach rather than what you are doing. One of the benefits is the same script (which will be shorter than yours now) with no regard to the amount of content, be it 2 boxes x 2 answers, or 10 x 10. You need (mostly) 2 behaviors: answer object (draggable, can be dropped) and box-drop-area that accepts a single answer and then rejects every next one.

Comment: i hoping that you can show me some example by using the example i have,just a bit of example is enough,

Comment: I am glad you asked. I just happen to have two answers here, both drag-n-drop related, both illustrate algorithmic approach (adding more draggable objects or drop areas do not inflate the code), both commented (one heavily commented) so you can read and learn the ideas behind the approach. One: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53249946/4687633 Two: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42542667/4687633